# C++: locking mechanism with a container of a set of pointers

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a

```
std::map<std::string, Something*> myMap
```

where the `Something*` can be locked because they can be accessed from different threads.

Since entries in the `myMap` can be inserted, I also have a global lock to avoid concurrency during the "fetch" phase.

```
myMapLock.lock();
Something* some = myMapLock[key];
myMapLock.unlock();
some.lock();
// do something with some
some.unlock();
```

This structure cannot work well if I want also to delete entries in the `myMap`, since I could remove something that is still locked by someone else (but has already unlocked the `myMap`).

Do you know of any pattern that would solve my problem?

Comment: If `Something*` can be accessed from different threads only through general map lock, it doesn't need to have it's own lock: `myMapLock.lock(); Something* some = myMapLock[key]; // do something with some myMapLock.unlock();` This is OK if all threads work by the same way.

Comment: The two-level locking mechanism is due to performance reasons. One thread can lock a single Something* for a long while: having a mutex for each Something* improves performances. The global lock is necessary, since I can also add/remove things from the std::map

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::shared_ptr<Something>` instead of `Something *`. The `Something` object will be deleted when the reference count to it equals 0. So if a thread has locked `Something` object (and get a copy of `std::shared_ptr<Something>` from `myMap`) then the `Something` object will not be deleted even if other thread removes the entry with this `Something` object from `myMap`.

Comment: So your solution is: keeping the two-level locking mechanism, but never do a "delete Something*" explicitly, when I have to delete a Something*, I lock the whole map, remove the entry and let the shared_ptr do the actual delete, right?

Comment: Yes. If you need to use the two-level locking mechanism.